# How to create an array of linearly spaced points using numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to create an array of equally spaced points using numpy, as below:

```
array([ 0.        ,  0.05263158,  0.10526316,  0.15789474,  0.21052632,
    0.26315789,  0.31578947,  0.36842105,  0.42105263,  0.47368421,
    0.52631579,  0.57894737,  0.63157895,  0.68421053,  0.73684211,
    0.78947368,  0.84210526,  0.89473684,  0.94736842,  1.        ])
```

This array is 20 points between 0 and 1, all with the same amount of space between them.

Looking at the documentation for [`numpy.array`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html), however, I don't see a way to do this by passing in an extra parameter. Is this possible to do as a quick-and-easy one-liner?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use linspace.

```
np.linspace(0, 1, 20)
```

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html

Comment: I knew there had to be some function for this. Thanks for the find. It's too late at night for me to still be up here. :p