# Python predetermined list lenght from a range of variable numbers?

Tags: python, list, numpy

i'm trying to implement a function that returns a list of n elements from a range of numbers from the same list. I find it hard to explain so let me just show the goal with some code:

I have the following:

```
input_list = [2.3, 4.5, 6.7, 7.1, 7.6, 8.1, 9]
```

I would like to have a resulting list with the same number of elements of the input list but with them gradually ranging from 2.3 to 9

I tried `numpy.arange()` but the problem is i don't know what's the step of the range.

I could try:

```
low_value= input_list [:1][0]
high_value = input_list [-1:][0]
desired_step = ( high_value  - low_value ) / len(input_list)

wanted_range = numpy.arange(low_value, high_value, desired_step)
```

Unfortunatelly the code above gives the resulting list:

```
resulting_list = [3.25, 4.21, 5.17, 6.12, 7.08, 8.04, 9.0]
```

As you can see the first number is 3.25 and not the original 2.3

If i try to use `desired_step = high_value / len(input_list)` it just breaks and doesn't always return the correct number of elements depending on the lenght of the list and the highest number

I don't know if this case scenario has a particular name but i'd appreciate any suggestion on how to solve it. Thanks!

Comment: can you post the expected `resulting_list` ?

Comment: `numpy.linspace` might be more convenient for this case. You can specify start, end and number of samples (rather than calculating the step yourself) - https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create an array of linearly spaced points using numpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39698121/how-to-create-an-array-of-linearly-spaced-points-using-numpy) If you don't want a linearly spaced array, please specify what you mean by "gradually"

Comment: Also, you can do `input_list[0]` to get the first element of the list and `input_list[-1]` to get the last value

Comment: To be clear, the result you want is something like `[2.3, 3.42, 4.53, 5.65, 6.77, 7.88, 9.0]`? There isn't a particular "name for this scenario", but also the **isn't a question about programming, it's a question about arithmetic**. The goal is to **calculate** the step size, i.e. to figure out the **mathematical** steps that are needed. That is, in order to use `arange`. But you don't want to use `arange`; you want to use `linspace`, as in the linked duplicate.